# scope is not working outside ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="obj in strA">
       obj.str = {{obj}}
       <input ng-model="obj" />
    </li>
</ul>
obj in <code>{{ strA.a1 }}</code> 
obj in <code>{{ strA.a2 }}</code>
```

### Controller

```
$scope.strA = {
  a1: "abc",
  a2: "bcd"
};
```

When I change the value in text box, obj inside ng-repeat changes. but value wrapped by  don't change

Here is the codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLyrxm
Why is it so? as per my knowledge, both the value should be change

Comment: This is because ng-repeat creates a child  scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ngRepeat creates new child scope. It means that in each repeated `li` there is a new scope and with ngMOdel you are binding to this local scope. You could do something like this instead:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in strA">
    obj.str = {{value}}
    <input ng-model="strA[key]" />
</li>
```

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adBKVd?editors=101

Comment: That mean I need to specify key to bind. what you mean by new child scope?

Comment: @dfsq -  Good attempt

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers It means that the the scope (`$scope`) is different inside of each `li`. you think you change `obj` inside of the loop, but you actually modifying new local (child) scope property, which shadows outer scope `obj`. So what I did is provided a direct reference to the outer scope `obj`. This is related to how [prototypical object inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) works in JS. I recommend to get familiar with this topic, this is very important.